# Adding Data To Email Through Loop In Python

Tags: python, html, smtplib

I am attempting to iterate through a map containing arrays to an HTML email template. I can print out the data in the array but, the data does not show up in the array after finishing the loop.

```
  html_data = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html lang="en">
        <head></head>
        <body>




        <br>
        <br>

        Date: {{date}}
        <br>

        <br>
        Hi,
        <br>

        <br>
        Today's Picks Are in:


        <br>

        <br>
        <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th align='left'>Stock</th>
                    <th>Pick</th>
                    <th>Detail</th>
                    <th>Change</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <td align='left'>{{ picks }}</td>

            {% for pick in picks %}
                <tr>
                
                    <td align='center'> {{pick.stock}} </td>
                    # <td align='center'> {{pick.prices}} </td>
                    # <td align='center'>{{pick.option_details}}</td>
                    # <td align='center'>{{pick.change}}</td>
                    </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>




        <p>If you would like to be removed from this list, please contact customer service: <mail_to="devs@hscottindustriescom">HScottIndustries</a> </p>

"""
```

Picks is the mapped array

> picks = {
> 'stocks': stocks,
> 'prices': stock_price,
> 'option_details': options_details,
> 'change': change
> }

The data from picks is added here.

```
msg = MIMEText(Environment().from_string(html_data).render(picks=picks, date=date_original), "html")
```

The output is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html lang="en">
        <head></head>
        <body>




        <br>
        <br>

        Date: 07-05-2022
        <br>

        <br>
        Hi,
        <br>

        <br>
        Today's Picks Are in:


        <br>

        <br>
        <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th align='left'>Stock</th>
                    <th>Pick</th>
                    <th>Detail</th>
                    <th>Change</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <td align='left'>{'stocks': ['WPP', 'NEX', 'PTEN'], 'prices': ['45.21', '8.37', '13.39'], 'option_details': ['na', 'NEX Jul 15 2022 $7.50 Put', 'PTEN Jul 15 2022 $13.00 Put'], 'change': ['-10.19%', '-11.52%', '-11.53%']}</td>

            
                <tr>
                
                    <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    </tr>
            
                <tr>
                
                    <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    </tr>
            
                <tr>
                
                    <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    </tr>
            
                <tr>
                
                    <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'>  </td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    # <td align='center'></td>
                    </tr>
            

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>




        <p>If you would like to be removed from this list, please contact customer service: <a href="https://hscottindustriescom">HScottIndustries</a> </p>



        <footer class="main-footer">
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2022 <mail_to="devs@HScottIndustries.com">HScottIndustries LLC</a></strong>
```

How do I add the get the data to iterate correctly to the corresponding fields?

Comment: You are saying picks is an array, but you posted a dict. If you iterate over a dict, you get the dictionary keys. so picks would need to be something like this in order to work: [{ 'stocks': stocks, 'prices': stock_price, 'option_details': options_details, 'change': change }]
Also mind that you wrote 'stock' without s in the HTML and with s in the dict.
And perhaps it would be helpful to add which framework you are using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over picks, which right now is a dictionary, meaning you will get dictionary keys in return. You can either format picks in a different way, or use an index. This format should work:

```
picks = [
  {
     'stocks': 'WPP',
     'prices': '45.21',
     'option_details': 'na',
     'change': '-10.19%'
  },
  {
     'stocks': 'NEX',
     'prices': ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Alternatively you can pass picks as zipped arrays in your view:

```
zipped_picks = zip(*picks.values())
```

Then access them with:

```
{% for pick in zipped_picks %}
   <div> {{pick.0}} <div>
   <div> {{pick.1}} <div>
   <div> {{pick.2}} <div>
   <div> {{pick.3}} <div>
{% endfor %}
```